# How to programatically detect if code is running in nuitka compiled or python interpreted mode

Tags: python, nuitka

Can anyone say how to detect if code is running in an exe created by Nuitka or in a normal python interpreter?

I think I would ideally like an "**is_nuitka**" flag that would be set to True when compiled and presumably not exist at all when not compiled.

Could then use code like this:

```
if '__is_nuitka__' in locals() or '__is_nuitka__' in globals():
    print('debug info: running in nuitka mode')
```

Any suggestions? Is there anything like this available? any alternative approaches?

Comment: I am looking for a solution for that question as well. Did you find a solutin?

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Nuitka [0.6.2](https://nuitka.net/posts/nuitka-release-062.html), you can use this code:

```py
is_nuitka = "__compiled__" in globals()
```

Comment: I wish there were something like sys.pypy_version_info for nuitka.  Checking to see if something is compiled isn't necessarily going to continue working as more Python compilers are created.

Answer (score -2):

The first idea is to check sys.argv[0] like

```
if '.exe' in sys.argv[0]:
    # compiled
```

Comment: `python my_script_to_modify_.exe_files.py` would already break your assumptions.

Comment: if sys.argv[0].endswith('.exe')
then =)

Comment: WIth Nuitka 0.6.15.3 on a Linux system, the file extension is .bin, not .exe.  It would better to get something from the sys module - if nuitka had that.